# Can $f(x)=|x|^3$ be differentiated

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Can $f(x)=|x|^3$ be differentiated? If yes, how? If no, why?

What I've tried: 
lim as $h$ tends to $0$ of $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} (3(x+h)^2|x=h|-3x^2|x|)/h$$

However, I have no idea how to proceed from here. Please help :(

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: draw a picture showing what happens near $x=0$.

Comment: $f'(x)=3x|x|.$  Do $x=0,x\gt0,x\lt0$ as separate cases.

Comment: At $x \neq 0$, it's obvious. At $0$, $\frac{f(x)}{x} = \frac{|x|^3}{x} = \operatorname{sgn}(x)\ x^2 \xrightarrow[x\to 0] \ 0 $

Comment: You should say $x$ ranges over the reals.  Not the complexes... The answers seem to assume that anyway.

Answer (score 2):

*From the definition, we will check whether $f^\prime(0)$ is well-defined.*

$f$ is "clearly" infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, so the only question is differentiability at $0$.

But for $x\neq 0$,
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \frac{\lvert x\rvert^3}{x} = \lvert x\rvert^2\frac{\lvert x\rvert}{x}
$$
Since $\frac{\lvert x\rvert}{x}$ is bounded (it is either $1$ or $-1$, so always in $[-1,1]$) and $\lvert x\rvert^2\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}0$, the overall quantity has a limit at $0$:
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} \xrightarrow[x\to0]{} 0
$$
meaning by definition that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ (and, by the above discussion, everywhere).

Comment: You could simplify by just saying $(f(x)-f(0)/(x-0)-0| = |x^3/x|= |x^2| \to 0.$

Comment: Yes, indeed. ${}{}{} $

Comment: Alternatively, the limits as $x\to 0$ from both the right and left are $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You already know $x^3$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty),$ and that $-x^3$ is differentiable on $(-\infty,0).$ So all you have to worry about is $f'(0).$